# Calling Generic HTTP Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a scenario which I have to get data through generic handler and bind the table with data, I am not sure about the way I have addressed the generic handler, any help please? here is my code which I have written so far.

```
            public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
              string json = this.GetUsersJason();
        
              json = String.Format("{0};",json);
       
              context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
              context.Response.Write(json);
            }

                private string GetUsersJason()
                {
                    List<object> Users = new List<object>();
        
                    DataTable Usersdt = new DataTable();
                    Usersdt = UMDal.GetUsers();
        
                    if (Usersdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow row in Usersdt.Rows)
                        {
                            Users.Add(row["UserId"].ToString());
                            Users.Add(row["UserName"].ToString());
                        }
                        return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Users));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DbUtilities.ShowMessage("No record found !", true,null, null);
                        return "";
                    }
        
                }
```

**Here is my client side code.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
    
                // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE 
                $.getJSON("../GenericHandlers/UsersGHandler.ashx",
                    function (data) {
                        var User = '';
    
                        // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS 
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
    
                            //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING 
                            // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT 
                            User += '<tr>';
                            User += '<td>' +
                                value.UserId + '</td>';
    
                            User += '<td>' +
                                value.UserName + '</td>';
    
                            User += '</tr>';
                        });
    
                        
                        $('#tblusers').append(user);
                    });
            }); 
        </script>
```

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: I am not sure the way I called generic handler  $.getJSON("../GenericHandlers/UsersGHandler.ashx") is correct

Comment: @jawed - Other than the fact the content type should be `text/json` instead of `text/j**a**son` I am not seeing an issue

Comment: Not working yet.